# How to correctly parse XML attributes and append in list with Python?

Tags: python, xml, list, parsing, elementtree

How can I correctly parse a XML file (config.xml) with elementtree?

With the function `getting_config_from_file()` (the goal is to retreive a list with all the subjects **id**s to use later. But this function actually doesn't return anything. I also think that for some reason it is not even entering the `for` statement. What could I be doing differently?

here is my function:

```
def getting_config_from_file():
    tree = ET.parse('config.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    parsed_subjects = []
    for x in root[0]:
        parsed_subjects.append(x.attrib)
    print(parsed_subjects)
    return parsed_subjects
```

and here is what my xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<all_configs>
    <subjects>
        <subject>
            <id>EB101</id>
            <subject_name>Cálculo I</subject_name>
            <classes_no>1</classes_no>
            <pre_reqs></pre_reqs>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <id>SI100</id>
            <subject_name>Algoritmos e Programação de Computadores I</subject_name>
            <classes_no>2</classes_no>
            <pre_reqs></pre_reqs>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <id>SI120</id>
            <subject_name>Lógica Matemática</subject_name>
            <classes_no>1</classes_no>
            <pre_reqs></pre_reqs>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <id>SI201</id>
            <subject_name>Estrutura de Dados I</subject_name>
            <classes_no>2</classes_no>
            <pre_reqs></pre_reqs>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <id>SI250</id>
            <subject_name>Economia e Finanças</subject_name>
            <classes_no>3</classes_no>
            <pre_reqs>SI100</pre_reqs>
        </subject>
    </subjects>
    <parameters>
        <parameter>
            <parameter_name>Below Average</parameter_name>
            <min_grade>0</min_grade>
            <max_grade>5</max_grade>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameter_name>Average</parameter_name>
            <min_grade>5</min_grade>
            <max_grade>7</max_grade>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameter_name>Above Average</parameter_name>
            <min_grade>7</min_grade>
            <max_grade>10</max_grade>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
</all_configs>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml file should not have `</xml>` in the end, and it may not parse as a result. Notwithstanding that, `.attrib` will look for the attributes of the element. `subject` element does not have any attribute and as a result, an empty list is returned.

To get the `id` for every `subject`, we need to access first element inside the for loop. Here is how it may look like:

```
 def getting_config_from_file():
    tree = ET.parse('config.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    parsed_subjects = []
    for x in root[0]: # access each subject
        parsed_subjects.append(x[0].text) # every x is an element. 0 refers to the first element.
    print(parsed_subjects)
    return parsed_subjects
```

Hope this helps.